# SQL Server : declaring a cursor with a PARAMETER

Tags: sql-server, cursor

This question is mostly to confirm a (sad) conclusion I reached after some googling.

I need to use a `CURSOR` in SQL Server 2012 in which there is a `WHERE` clause that depends on a parameter, something like:

```
...
DECLARE @MyParam INT ;

DECLARE My_Cur CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT A 
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE B = @MyParam
...
...

SET @MyParam = 2 ;
...
...
OPEN My_Cur 

WHILE ...
BEGIN

    FETCH My_Cur INTO ...
END;
```

When executing this, I get no results at all. If, instead of the variable in the cursor declaration, I deploy the value 2, results come out as needed.

This works perfectly in other DBMS (e.g. ORACLE).

Is it possible at all to have this type of parameterized cursors? If not, can anyone suggest a workaround?

I found some posts suggesting to declare the cursor AFTER the value is assigned to the variable but... this looks to me a very strange limitation.

Thanks.

Comment: The best "work around" would be to eliminate the cursor entirely. Looping in sql is far less than optimal and almost always can be replaced by a simpler and faster set based approach. And no, what you are asking is not possible. The cursor is your result set that you are looping through row by row. The very nature of your request suggests to me a cursor is not the best way to handle this. Post some real details and we can help you get rid of the cursor.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable before the cursor is declared.  That being said, it would be better to refactor to use set-based processing if possible.

Comment: I could not find an example In Books Online or anywhere else that illustrates using a variable in a cursor declare. There is such a thing as a cursor variable but that stores the entire cursor in a variable but that is not what you are looking for. So the answer is, for TSQL, you cannot do it.

Comment: Oracle is far better optimized to use cursors than SQL server. Cursors are not usually the best choice in SQL server.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, select statements can include variables or parameters. You can find an example in the SQL Server Books Online here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx.

Comment: I hate to argue with Dan Guzman, a real SQL Server expert and well deserved MVP. Of course a 'regular' select statements can contain variables and/or parameters. But I have yet to see (including the URL you posted) where a declare cursor select statement contains a variable.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman. Yes, I saw posts about declaring the cursor AFTER the variable gets its value, but was hoping it was a dream and not real life. As for avoid using cursors, **I couldn't disagree more!**. T-SQL (as well as others) is a programming language like an other, except for its specialization on DB activities. I've seen too many pieces of code almost fully based on SELECT statements - impossible to understand. Many years ago there were two concepts that had value: _SW Design_ and _SW Engineering_. From there I coined this: _You write code for others, not for you_.

Comment: @FDavidov, SQL is not like other programming languages. It is declarative rather than procedural, where one specifies the desired result rather than how to accomplish the task. The optimizer's job is to figure out how to do that as efficiently as possible.  Procedural constructs like cursors and T-SQL extensions tie the hands of the optimizer.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I think there is no black-white approach (for some good reason, all platforms provide rather powerful programing methods/tools). It all comes down to how these tools are used. Let's agree that someone with enough programming experience would normally know how to avoid jeopardizing the job of the compilers (in any language!). I'm using cursors for many years and no single time faced performance issues with that. And yes, it is sometimes worth paying some **reasonable** price on performance on behalf of maintainability of the code.